# How to dynamically add models to tensorflow server

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I am new to Tensorflow serving and am looking for a way to dynamically add models to TF Serving running in a Docker image. My goal (if it is possible) is to have a TF Server Docker image that can consume new models or new versions of an existing model while the Docker image is running.

Answer (score 0):

ReloadConfig API will help you.